# Proving that Android app never uses the internet

Tags: android, google-play

Is there any way to prove to an Android mobile app user that your app never makes a single call to the network?

Answer (score 3):

If you do not have the `INTERNET` permission, you should not be able to do any network communications.

So, one proof would be to not have the `INTERNET` permission. This may require you to specifically remove it via `tools:remove` or something, as third-party libraries might request it (even if you are not using features of those libraries that require that permission).

If your concern is that the user will not be able to tell that you lack this permission, or may not trust the permission system, or may not trust that the permission is needed for network access, then I do not know that there is much that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

1. Simply stating that your app does not require internet connection, because it does not use it, would be enough (for me at least)
2. You could just redirect user to
   [image]

this page in settings